# Check for API Protocol to ensure no downtime

Tags: ssl, soap, https, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms mobile application that connects with a soap web service. The same domain hosts multiple web apps. I need to update the domain with SSL, but I do not want any downtime in the application.

My first thought was to check see if the https url responds and if not to check for http.

How can I check the protocol of the domain from a mobile app? Is there any better idea to accomplish this with no downtime?

More Info: The solution I am proposing is only so that there is no downtime while the application passes review in the Appstore and Google play. After that I will release a second update to allow https only. I need to have no downtime in the applications using the API while the transition happens. I am not saying that this is a permanent solution or a good practice.

Comment: You should not fall back from HTTPS to HTTP. If HTTPS fails to work, stop it.

Comment: You should be going the other way. Assuming you are using HTTP for transport, you should redirect HTTP to HTTPS during the transition and update your app to only allow HTTPS connections.

Comment: The solution I am proposing is only so that there is no downtime while the application passes review in the Appstore and Google play. After that I will release a second update to allow https only. I need to have no downtime in the applications using the API while the transition happens.